# Bootstrap 3 change grid column count and gutter width on specific containers using SASS mixin

Tags: grid, twitter-bootstrap-3, sass, mixins

I am trying to change the grid-column count and gutter-width within specific containers.

The obvious and most fastest way would be to use a mixin in Bootstrap SASS.

Is there not one mixin that handles all of this in one? I struggling to see one runs all the mixins in _grid.scss

For example, I'm looking for something like this.

```
@mixin new-grid-system($grid-columns, $grid-gutter-width);
```

-

```
.gallery {
   @include new-grid-system('10', '10px');
}

.gforms {
   @include new-grid-system('9', '10px');
}
```

If not, any one got any ideas?

---

**UPDATE**

After a little persistence , I worked it out and made my own...

```
@mixin new-grid-system($new-grid-columns, $new-grid-gutter-width) {

    $grid-columns: $new-grid-columns;
    $grid-gutter-width: $new-grid-gutter-width;  

    .row {
        @include make-row();
    }

    @include make-grid-columns();
    @include make-grid(xs);
    @media (min-width: $screen-sm-min) {
        @include make-grid(sm);
    }
    @media (min-width: $screen-md-min) {
        @include make-grid(md);
    }
    @media (min-width: $screen-lg-min) {
        @include make-grid(lg);
    }

}
```

Just run like this...

```
.gallery {
   @include new-grid-system('10', '10px');
}
```

Comment: Thanks, could you post your solution as an answer ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is my solution:

First set new vars (this is just for overal column setup, not for the specific changes) in **vars.scss**

```
/************************************
***** column vars
*************************************/

$new-columns :                  12;
$new-gutter-width :             40px;

$grid-columns :                 $new-columns;
$grid-gutter-width :            $new-gutter-width;
```

Here is the mixin which I keep in **mixins.scss**

```
@mixin column-adjust($column,$gutter) {

    // set custom variables for our grid structure
    $grid-columns: $column !global;
    $grid-gutter-width: $gutter !global;

    .row {
        @include make-row();
    }
    @include make-grid-columns();
    // @include make-grid(xs);
    @media (min-width: $screen-sm-min) {
        @include make-grid(sm);
    }
    @media (min-width: $screen-md-min) {
        @include make-grid(md);
    }
    @media (min-width: $screen-lg-min) {
        @include make-grid(lg);
    }

    // reset global vars;
    $grid-columns: $new-columns !global;
    $grid-gutter-width: $new-gutter-width !global;

}
```

Make sure the order of the scss import is like this..

```
@import 'vars';
@import 'mixins';
```

Mixin example use is like so...

```
/************************************
***** grid changes
*************************************/

.grid {
    &.grid-10-across {
        @include column-adjust(10, $grid-gutter-width );
    }
    &.grid-24-across {
        @include column-adjust(24, $grid-gutter-width );
    }
}

.gutter-slim {
    &.gutter-slim-10 {
        @include column-adjust($new-columns, 10px );
    }
    &.gutter-slim-6 {
        @include column-adjust($new-columns, 6px );
    }
}
```

Hope this helps. Feel free to improve :-)